# How to secure memcached?

Tags: security, memcached

In Debian, I have installed  memcached  (using [this guide](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-install-memcached-on-ubuntu-for-drupal)) to lower the otherwise unmanageable load on mysql database. The database is on a separate server, and memcached and Varnish are on the front server. Is it a potential security hole to leave memcached unprotected by a firewall? If so, how should I secure it? The situation is especially worrisome,as I've received (unproved) reports of cookie thefts on the server. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just block the memcached port in firewall and allow access only from the database server. This  should give you some protection. Also you can bring up a SSL tunnel between the mysql and memcached server and make the memcached-mysql data flow through it only.

For the SSL tunnel you can use IPSEC, to set it up you can follow the tutorial at http://wiki.debian.org/IPsec or http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ipsec.tunnel.html

For blocking the port for all ip's except one you can issue an iptables command like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 2.2.2.2/32 -p tcp --destination-port 11211 -j ALLOW
iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --destination-port 11211 -j DROP
```

or:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s !2.2.2.2/32 -p tcp --destination-port 11211 -j DROP
```

Also as I understand your webserver and memcached server are on the same machine? If so then it is your webserver that will communicate with memcached rather then the mysql server. It will just either get the data from cache or if it's not present in the cache will get it from the mysql server. In this case it's just enough to bind memcached to localhost so only your webserver can access memcached using php, ruby, python or any other language code, this should as safe as it can be.

Comment: Will you please elaborate on how to do these, assuming that my web server's IP is  at 1.1.1.1 and database servers' Ip 2.2.2.2? Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer with more info.

Comment: As you notices, memcached is on the webserver, so I think you need to edit the iptables rules accrodingly.

Comment: Well - if it's on the webserver then probably there is no need to do that, it's better to just bind it to localhost on the webserver since it will be the webserver which will use it directly and not mysql. This will really be the safest option.

Comment: So, just to clarify, to bind memcached to the localhost. I need to put 127.0.0.1 instead of 2.2.2.2 in the rules above. Correct?

Comment: No, you'll need to configure memcached to run on localhost like described here - http://blog.codesherpas.com/on_the_path/2010/08/securing-memcache-in-2-minutes.html - it shows how to configure memcached to listen only on localhost. This is not done in the firewall.

Comment: Well the guide in the link is for Centos 5.3, and while it is interesting, not really applicable for Debian 6, as /etc/memcached.conf has already '-l 127.0.0.1' uncommented by default.

Comment: Then you're all set already, memcached listens only on localhost and thus is secured.